# Usage of the verb "pipe"

Tags: verbs

In the following passage from the book "Do androids dream of electric sheep?":

*A merry little surge of electricity piped by automatic alarm from the mood organ beside his bed awakened Rick Deckard.*

What is the verb "piped" actually conveying, was Rick awakened by a "merry" pipe sound activated by automatic alarm or was he awakened by the "merry surge of electricity" being piped (through a pipe) into him like an electric current passing through his body?

Comment: When music is piped in, that just means *sent* in, as originally channeled in by pipe.

Comment: In terms of an alarm meant to *wake him up*, the specific sense is given in [the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pipe#h2): "*(transitive verb)* **1 b**: to utter in the shrill tone of a pipe."

Comment: The quote is from a sci-fi novel, as I recall. But it’s meant to remind you of this: The pipe organ is a musical instrument that produces sound by driving pressurized air (called wind) through the organ pipes selected from a keyboard. (Wikipedia)